# ССП неоднородное?

Tags: ссп

Верно ли найдено в тексте ССП неоднородного состава?

1. Щель выкопали неглубокую, но зато нарвали травы и устелили ее дно.
2. Ваш сержант Бога молит о тумане, коммунист, между прочим, и потому его молитва действенна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно. Союз ***но*** и лексический конкретизатор ***поэтому***  указывают на неоднородный состав ССП.